# Trouble with managing props in framework7-vue

Tags: vuejs2, html-framework-7

I'm having problems understanding how to pass props to page components

With Vue i can do

```
Vue.component("name", {props: ["example"]});
```

and use it like so
    `<name v-bind:example="parentData">{{example}}</name>`

and that works and it's fine but in framework7-vue each page is a component and they get switched at run-time so i have no `<pageElement></pageElement>` where i can set anything and so using `{{example}}` or `{{parentData}}` inside the page/component template does not work

The official docs do not seem to cover this topic
https://framework7.io/vue/navigation-router.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to work, but you can create a new data property in the component, then listen to the created hook, and set the property value to the prop value there.

```
Vue.component("name", {
              props: ["example"], 
              data() {return {myExample: null}}, 
              template: "<some-tag>{{myEaxmple}}</some-tag>",
              created() {this.myEaxmple = this.example}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define route for any page with props like this:

```
{
    path: '/About/:example',
    component: AboutPage,
}
```

I assume you've already defined prop for this page:

```
name: 'AboutPage',
props: ['example']
```

Then pass prop in any link to this page. For example:

```
<f7-list-item :link="'/About/' + PROP_VALUE">...</f7-list-item>
```

And inside page use `{{example}}` in template or `this.example` in code.